# ggplot2 scale x date?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make the ticks in the following graph daily instead of every 2 days.

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(
    Timestamp = structure(
      c(
        1441837436, 1441843661,
        1441885583, 1441966341, 1441985621, 1442048926, 1442321691, 1442329081,
        1442349761, 1442408140, 1442417679, 1442508871, 1442513339, 1442513395,
        1442514010, 1442525088, 1442553226, 1442562304
      ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct",
                                  "POSIXt")
    ), number = 7:24
  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-18L), .Names = c("Timestamp", "number")
)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Timestamp, y = number)) +
  geom_line(size=2) + geom_point(size=5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 2))
```

I tried adding `+ scale_x_date(breaks = "1 day")` but I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

I also tried `scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct('2015-09-09'), as.POSIXct('2015-09-19')), breaks = 1)`

---

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Timestamp, y = number)) +
  geom_line(size=2) + geom_point(size=5) + scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 day")
Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") : non-character argument
```

does not work either :(

---

I tried in two different computers:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.1.9003 taucharts_0.3.2   
[3] dplyr_0.4.3        fasttime_1.0-1    
[5] lubridate_1.3.3    readr_0.1.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1        digest_0.6.8      
 [3] assertthat_0.1     grid_3.2.2        
 [5] plyr_1.8.3         R6_2.1.1          
 [7] gtable_0.1.2       DBI_0.3.1         
 [9] magrittr_1.5       scales_0.3.0.9000 
[11] stringi_0.5-5      lazyeval_0.1.10   
[13] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_3.2.2       
[15] stringr_1.0.0      htmlwidgets_0.5   
[17] munsell_0.4.2      parallel_3.2.2    
[19] colorspace_1.2-6   htmltools_0.2.6   
[21] memoise_0.2.1
```

2.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3        ggplot2_1.0.1.9003

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-6  scales_0.3.0.9000 lazyeval_0.1.10   magrittr_1.5      R6_2.1.1          assertthat_0.1   
 [7] plyr_1.8.3        parallel_3.2.1    DBI_0.3.1         tools_3.2.1       gtable_0.1.2      Rcpp_0.12.1      
[13] grid_3.2.1        munsell_0.4.2
```

Comment: You have a `POSIXct` variable and need to use a datetime scale, e.g., `scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 day")`.

Comment: I tried, but it gives me this error: `Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") : non-character argument`

Comment: The option of @Roland works for me. Alternatively you could use `as.Date(Timestamp)`.

Comment: Please provide the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @Roland done. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not the ggplot2 version on CRAN. If you use the devel version you are on your own (you probably should report this issue).

Comment: It's not a bug, see my answer below

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `scales` package. It looks like you need to use the function `date_breaks`, rather than just `breaks` to get proper labels:

EDIT: it appears the argument has been changed to date_breaks:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Timestamp, y = number)) +
    geom_line(size=2) +
    geom_point(size=5) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 2)) + 
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day")
```

original:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Timestamp, y = number)) +
    geom_line(size=2) +
    geom_point(size=5) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 2)) + 
    scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 day"))
```

[image]

If you want to change how the date is displayed in the label, you can use `date_format` inside the `scale_x_datetime` call.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/man/scale_date.Rd) it seems like you should be able to use `scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day")`.

Comment: I had code that use to work, but then just recently started giving me the `Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") : non-character argument` error.  The problem was fixed by changing `scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b"), breaks='1 month')` to `scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b"), date_breaks='1 month')`.  Given that it used to work, perhaps this issue only arose with a recent update to `R` or `ggplot2`?  I am using v2.1.0 of `ggplot2` and 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) Fire Safety of `R`.

Comment: Indeed, it used to work. Now ``breaks``  has become ``date_breaks``

Comment: Same thing here, I was trying to re-purpose some old code, and what used to work with:
`breaks = "1 hour"`,
now only works with
`breaks = date_breaks("1 hour")`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 day"), try for 
scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day")