# How do I get ggplot to break x-axis on each day?

Tags: r, date, time-series, bar-chart

I would like to get a bar chart that shows a certain quantity per day. However, ggplot is not showing the days seperatly, but summerizes per month. How do I get ggplot to break x-axis on each day?

This is the code that I am using:

```
ggplot(aes(x=d.data$a, y= d.data$b), data = d.data) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 day') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

After running the code above the following error occurs:`Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") : non-character argument`

The following data is used as input:

```
d.data <- structure(list(a = structure(c(16771, 16772, 16773, 16774, 16776, 
    16777, 16780, 16781, 16782, 16784, 16785, 16787, 16788, 16789, 
    16790, 16791, 16792, 16796, 16797, 16798, 16799, 16800, 16801, 
    16802, 16803, 16804, 16805, 16806, 16807, 16808, 16809, 16810, 
    16811, 16812, 16813, 16814, 16815, 16816, 16817, 16818, 16819, 
    16820, 16821, 16822, 16823, 16824, 16825, 16826, 16827, 16828, 
    16829, 16830, 16831, 16832, 16833, 16834, 16835, 16836, 16837
    ), class = "Date"), b = c(5613L, 1374L, 6179L, 2913L, 6628L, 
    3265L, 1763L, 10678L, 7308L, 8686L, 11805L, 4988L, 6584L, 11847L, 
    271L, 8125L, 11227L, 6969L, 8407L, 5083L, 8188L, 10500L, 4592L, 
    8691L, 1121L, 1150L, 3154L, 11724L, 6059L, 2573L, 10244L, 1008L, 
    10938L, 7356L, 1931L, 5182L, 1541L, 10449L, 9948L, 2418L, 10384L, 
    11416L, 8994L, 10652L, 6231L, 3777L, 6079L, 10041L, 10922L, 7410L, 
    1695L, 10890L, 390L, 5635L, 6882L, 6892L, 2807L, 4472L, 5696L
    )), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -59L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using your data, you first need to make sure that your date column is from the class `POSIXct`, then you may use the ggplot code below:

```
d.data$a <- as.POSIXct(d.data$a)

ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b), data = d.data) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 day") +     ### changed
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

This yields the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason that the date column should be `POSIXct` rather than just `Date`. Does it change the way in which `ggplot` renders it?

Comment: @Eumenedies I tried it first with class `Date`. This returned the following error: `Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only`

Comment: isn't that just because you used `scale_x_datetime` instead of `scale_x_date`?

Comment: @Eumenedies True: `scale_x_datetime` expects class `POSIXct`, `scale_x_date` expects class `Date`, and `scale_x_time` expects class `hms`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can specify `breaks` in `scale_x_date()`, in order to specify daily breaks in the format using, the correct argument is `date_breaks`. You can see an example of its use in the help for `scale_x_date()` by running `?scale_x_date`.

Thus your code should read:

```
ggplot(aes(x=a, y= b), data = d.data) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 day') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: True, but the question was why the code was throwing an error and how the first line is written has exactly zero bearing on that.

Comment: You get that error because you imported the data in the wrong format. I did not include a conversion in my answer for the simple reason that, had the data used in the original question not been `Date` formatted, that error would have been thrown instead of the error quoted. Since the error in the question occurred, column a was obviously already a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the command changed *see ([ggplot2 scale x date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653730/ggplot2-scale-x-date)): it appears the argument has been changed to date_breaks